# How can I deserialize a nested React Element which is an elemen of a nested object inside an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, serialization, deserialization

Hey guys I have a tough one here

I need to store and retrieve an object with nested elements and a function which returns serialized in the clients localStorage. As for the storing and retrieving, it works. But I am having an issue with functions which have been stringyfied, but won't go back to be actual functions anymore.

Here is an example of an array element:

[image]

As far as I am aware, this is called serialized in the JSON-Jargon. And the goal would be to unserialize them again in order to make them function again. In order to be able to store functions in the JSON format, I had "replace and revive" the arrays which had to be stored.

```
  let replacer = (key, value) => {
if (typeof value === "function") {
  return value.toString();
}
return value;
```

I turn functions to string and return them to the JSON. I invoke this helper function like this:

```
 localStorage.setItem(
                  "currentConfiguration",
                  JSON.stringify(
                    tableRef.current.dataManager.columns,
                    replacer,
                    2
                  )
```

Here is the code which is actually supposed to do: Undo what the replacer did and return actual functions instead of their strings.

```
let reviver = (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === "string" && value.indexOf("function ") === 0) {
      let functionTemplate = `(${value})`;
      return eval((functionTemplate));
    }
    return value;
  };
```

Currently I am facing this screen whenever I try to render:
[image]

Would appriciate if anyone could lend a helping hand